# How to manage application variables in a ReactJS app w/ gulp?

Tags: gulp, reactjs

I have some application/configurations variables, such as `MY_ENDPOINT`, that should point to `http://dev.myendpoint/` for dev and `http://myendpoint/` for production.  Where should I store this information in a ReactJS application that uses gulpjs (and flux)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using browserify, you can use the envify transform to provide compile time variables.

```
var envParams = {};

function bundle(){
  return gulp.src('src/app.js')
  .pipe(gulpBrowserify({
    transform: [
      'reactify',
      ['envify', envParams]
    ]
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
};

gulp.task('scripts-dev', function(){
  envParams = {MY_ENDPOINT: 'http://dev.myendpoint/'};
  return bundle();
});

gulp.task('scripts-prod', function(){
  envParams = {MY_ENDPOINT: 'http://myendpoint/'};
  return bundle();
});
```

And in your code:

```
fetch(process.env.MY_ENDPOINT + "api/foo')...
```

---

You can also supply env vars on the command line, however the gulp file will override them by default:

```
MY_ENDPOINT=something gulp scripts-dev
```

And to allow command line to take precedence:

```
envParams = {MY_ENDPOINT: process.env.MY_ENDPOINT || 'http://myendpoint/'};

// or with es6 shim
envParams = Object.assign({MY_ENDPOINT: 'http://myendpoint/'}, process.env);
```

---

You can also use envify before other transforms which require static strings, like brfs:

```
var config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(process.env.CONFIG_PATH));
```

Which will compile into:

```
var config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('/home/.../dev-config.json'));
```

And finally into:

```
var config = JSON.parse('{"foo": "bar"}');
```

Comment: Thanks.  This lead me to DefinePlugin for webpack.

Comment: @Bradford it'd be cool if you add an example in another answer, I'm sure it help out webpack users that end up here.